# How do i redirect to a page from php yii2.0 components?

Tags: session, redirect, yii2, timeout, components

I Have a component ,in which have one init() function which is to be called before each action.

I only need to check if the session is expired redirect the user to login.

Here is my code,
config/main.php coponents -

```
'MyGlobalClass'=>[
        'class'=>'common\components\MyGlobalClass'
    ],
```

and

```
'bootstrap' => ['log','MyGlobalClass'],
```

components/MyGlobalClass .php :

```
class MyGlobalClass extends \yii\base\Component{
public function init() {
    //echo "Hi";
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
    {
        //echo 'called';exit;
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('login'));
    }
    //parent::init();
}
```

}

so it is coming inside if{} but not redirecting to login page.

Comment: why not use access control?  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html

Comment: You are missing controller in createUrl:
`Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/login'));`

Comment: Thanks. but i am using url manager in which my login is referred with 'login', so no need to use site/login.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, it worked for me:

```
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('admin/page/signin');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this to send your response

```
Yii::$app->response->send();
```

but please review the guide for controller/action distinct access control
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('login'));
return;
```

Comment: Hey janhavi thanks. I am doing the same, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

correct way is :

```
 Yii::$app->response->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('site/logout'));
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you'll get an infinite redirect loop: The component is called on each controller call, redirection will never stop.

Better to manage it from `public function behaviors()` on each controller, check the [Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) section on [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

May be this one help you :)

```
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['user/login']);
```

or

```
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('user/login'));
```